# Make text load at the same time as scroll window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got text that loads instantly while the slideToggle is still animating causing the user to be able to see the text before the background slides into place. How can I get it so that the text either loads at the same speed as the slide animation or maybe after the slide animation completes?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.splash').hide(); //Initially form wil be hidden.

$('.about, .close').click(function(e){
    $('.splash').slideToggle(300);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: `slideToggle` accepts a callback function. You can place the code which displays the text in there.

Answer (score 2):

Modify `slideToggle` as follows:

```
$('.splash').slideToggle(300, function(){
    //code for displaying text here
});
```

The second parameter inside `slideToggle` is for the function on complete of the animation. You can learn more about slideToggle [here](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/).

Comment: @user2252219, in the fiddle, what exactly are you trying to display/hide on click of the `close` button?

Comment: Sorry my explanation was poor. Here's what it currently looks like (http://jsfiddle.net/Dar_T/m3b9w5da/3/). Basically when you click the name, you can see that the content sort of loads faster than the background can scroll causing it to be out of sync.